# Sprite Kit: SKSpriteNodes hanging off left side of screen despite (0,0) anchor points

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm adding an array of SKSpriteNodes (640px wide) directly to my SKScene:

```
  for (backgroundTile in backgroundTiles) {

    backgroundTile.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    backgroundTile.position = CGPointMake(BG_TILE_X_POS, tilePlacementPositionY);
    [self addChild:backgroundTile];
    tilePlacementPositionY += tileHeight;

  }
```

(BG_TILE_X_POS is 0.0)

But despite having an X position of 0.0 and their anchor points being set to (0.0,0.0) they still hang off the left side of the screen by 150px.

I can compensate that by giving them an X position of 150 and have also tried:

```
self.size = view.bounds.size;
```

…but that only enlarges the visible parts of the sprites so that they fill the screen; cropping off the top sprite.

I assume I'm making a rookie mistake but, looking through the documentation, nothing's striking me as obvious (which I guess it should be).

So, how do I position the sprites flush to the left edge? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is your Scene positioned at (0,0) too?

Comment: Yep, just double checked with an NSLog. Everything is 0.000000.

Comment: and if you NSLog the position of the sprites after adding them to scene, do they show their are positioned at x=0?

Comment: Yep. Logging sprites xpos before and after adding them to the scene as: 0.000000

Comment: So scene is at 0, sprites are at 0, could it have something to do with the iPhone simulator? or are you using a device?

Comment: I've been testing on the device but same thing also happens on the simulator.

Comment: self.size = view.bounds.size ensures your scene and view are the same size.  If this is causing a problem than you probably have a bigger problem.  I would venture so say your scene.size is not what you would expect for the device.  I had this issue where my scene was being drawn at some random resolution for all my devices yet the view size came back as expected.  Through me off big time

Comment: But when I set self.size = view.bounds.size it takes only one and half background tiles to file the screen vertically. Each tile is only meant to be 640x320px.

Answer (score 0):

I'd overlooked the obvious. I'd only created placeholder sprites at x2 resolution but stored them in their image sets as 1x resolution. Finally, with the setting:

```
self.size = view.bounds.size;
```

everything behaves as expected.

Silly mistake. I was convinced the problem was with the code, not the assets.